# Dump batch script output into a text file without specifing batchfile location beforehand

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

Im aware that i can get the output this way (to capture both standard and errors):

```
[batchFilePath] > [logFilePath] 2>&1
```

Or this way for standard output:

```
C:\MyBatchFile.bat > output.txt
```

**But is there a way to do this without specifying the location of the batch file itself?**

For example lets assume i run (just doubleclick to execute) C:\MyFolder\MyBatch.cmd and after i exit the batch file (or it completes) i can find the output in C:\MyFolder\MyBatch.txt

If so what code would i need to include in the batch file itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is adding `>> output.txt` at the end of every command outputing something of your batch file. It will add the output of your file at the end of `output.txt`

Or creating a second batch file which content would be `.\MyBatchFile.bat > output.txt`.

Answer (score 12):

Enclose your commands in round brackets. `MyBatchFile.bat`:

```
@echo off
REM setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(
  echo line one
  echo line two
  echo line three
) > "%~dpn0.txt"
```

Variables inside the brackets are evaluated all at once when `(` is encountered. Use `enabledelayedexpansion` to delay the evaluation.

Comment: thank you, saved me the hassle of having to create a wrapper